# Grouping Polygons by Attributes and by Distance Using GeoPandas and networkx

Tags: qgis, postgis, geopandas, pandas, networkx

I am working on creating a unique group ID for a parcel dataset I have containing 115k records. I have been attempting to do this with PostGIS ([Grouping Parcels with an ID based on conditions, Query Speed assistance](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/461098/grouping-parcels-with-an-id-based-on-conditions-query-speed-assistance?noredirect=1#comment753456_461098)), but have not been able to get it working correctly using the cluster functions available.

Since I don't have much experience with PostGIS and SQL, I decided to stop my efforts and attempt doing this with geopandas and networkx.

My requirements:
I am trying to group parcels and create a unique ID to represent these groups. Parcels should be grouped if they have the same parcel_owner value OR if they have the same parcel_owner_address value AND the parcels are within 90 meters of each other.

Here is my code.

```py
import pandas as pd
import networkx as nx
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.ops import unary_union
from shapely.geometry import Polygon

gdf = gpd.read_file('parcels_testing.gpkg')

# create a graph and add nodes
G = nx.Graph()
G.add_nodes_from(gdf.index)

# add edges based on name and address
for name, data in gdf.groupby('parcel_owner'):
    G.add_edges_from([(data.index[i], data.index[j]) for i in range(len(data)) for j in range(i + 1, len(data))])
for address, data in gdf.groupby('parcel_owner_address'):
    G.add_edges_from([(data.index[i], data.index[j]) for i in range(len(data)) for j in range(i + 1, len(data))])

components = list(nx.connected_components(G))

# create a new graph to handle distance-based grouping
G_distance = nx.Graph()
G_distance.add_nodes_from(gdf.index)

# add edges based on distance within each component
for component in components:
    sub_gdf = gdf.loc[list(component)]
    for i, row1 in sub_gdf.iterrows():
        for j, row2 in sub_gdf.iterrows():
            if i != j and row1['geometry'].distance(row2['geometry']) <= 90:
                G_distance.add_edge(i, j)

# find connected components based on distance
group_mapping = {}
for group_id, component in enumerate(nx.connected_components(G_distance)):
    for node in component:
        group_mapping[node] = group_id

# map the group id back to the GeoDataFrame
gdf['group_id'] = gdf.index.map(group_mapping)
```

It actually works really well from what I can tell. However, while testing data it appears to take about 1 minute to run a file containing 20k records, but for a file containing 50k records it is taking more than 4 minutes to run. Obviously, this does not scale for my purposes. I was hoping to eventually do this analysis on hundreds of thousands of records. Since I am iterating over the dataframe several times here (to create the edges based on name and address, and then again when I am adding edges based on distance), I imagine there is a much faster way to do this while being more organized.

Is there any way to do the above in a vectorized manner? I know the speed lag is most likely because I am iterating over all of the parcels, but I just can't think of a way around iteration in this scenario, since I need to check the parcels to see if they are within the distance parameter. Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

**EDIT: Updated Code**

I was able to speed it up significantly making the following changes, which resulted in a 50k record analysis going from 4 minutes to 1 minute and 30 seconds. However, I am still doing a lot of things inefficiently I fear, and 115k record analysis is taking around 6 minutes. Any further suggestions would be greatly apricated.

Current version:

```py
import itertools
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import networkx as nx
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.ops import unary_union
from shapely.geometry import Polygon

# Load data
gdf = gpd.read_file('parcels.gpkg')
gdf = gdf[['combined_owner_name', 'combined_owner_address', 'geometry']]

# create graph
G = nx.Graph()

# Add nodes
G.add_nodes_from(gdf.index)

# Group the data and create edges
for col in ['parcel_owner', 'parcel_owner_address']:
    grouped = gdf.groupby(col).indices
    G.add_edges_from([edge for group in grouped.values() for edge in itertools.combinations(group, 2)])

# find connected components
components = list(nx.connected_components(G))

# Create graph
G_distance = nx.Graph()

# Add nodes
G_distance.add_nodes_from(gdf.index)

# Pre-calculate the buffer geometries
gdf['buffered_geometry'] = gdf['geometry'].buffer(90)

# Add edges based on distance within each component
for component in components:
    sub_gdf = gdf.loc[list(component)]
    spatial_index = sub_gdf.sindex

    for i, row in sub_gdf.iterrows():
        buffered_geometry = row['buffered_geometry']

        possible_matches_index = list(spatial_index.intersection(buffered_geometry.bounds))
        possible_matches = sub_gdf.iloc[possible_matches_index]
        precise_matches = possible_matches[possible_matches.intersects(buffered_geometry)]
        G_distance.add_edges_from([(i, j) for j in precise_matches.index if i != j])

# Find connected components based on distance
group_mapping = {}
for group_id, component in enumerate(nx.connected_components(G_distance)):
    for node in component:
        group_mapping[node] = group_id

# Map the group id back to the GeoDataFrame
gdf['group_id'] = gdf.index.map(group_mapping)
gdf = gdf[['group_id', 'combined_owner_name', 'combined_owner_address', 'geometry']]
```

Comment: I'd use following workflow. Create combo column name_addindex. Group by it. Iterate every group, itertools combination by 2. If distance in pair less than 90, add pair to list. This list IS you graph, populate it by add_edges_from

Comment: Note some nodes, might be islands, take it into account during component no transfer

Comment: Hey @FelixIP not entirely sure what you mean. Maybe add some code to explain?

Comment: Vectorization of distance is only possible for points using scipy pdist method. Unfortunately count of points is limited by  available memory

Comment: Can you add a screenshot showing some parcels? Or even better share some test data

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't share the data here.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have geopandas, so I'll try to get close to it using ArcGis. This script

```
import pandas as pd
import itertools as itt

## create dataframe with geometries and names
aList =[]
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor("PARCELS",("OID@","Name","Shape@X","Shape@Y")) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:aList.append(row)
DF = pd.DataFrame(aList)
aList=[]
DF.columns = "FID","Name","X","Y"
DF.set_index("FID",inplace=True)

import networkx as nx
G = nx.Graph()
## iterate potential groups (repeat for address thing from here to end)
for name in DF.Name.unique():
    df = DF[DF.Name==name]
    for i,j in itt.combinations(df.index, 2):
        distance = math.hypot(df.X.loc[i]-df.X.loc[j],df.Y.loc[i]-df.Y.loc[j])
        if distance>=90.0:continue
        aList.append((i,j))
## add edges
G.add_edges_from(aList)
```

prints number of connected component equal to 21 for points shown:

[image]

Way more efficient solution can be done in ArcGIS using near table with limited search radius.

Comment: Hey Felix, thanks for taking the time to write this up. I am trying to stick to open source tools for this solution which is why I was using geopandas. If I get a license in the future I'll give this a go.

Comment: The only difference is distance calculation. I was hoping you understand idea: no need in 2 graphs, no need to add nodes to graph.